# How to select only the parent of an unordered list, using only CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Without changing the HTML, which pains me, how do I only select the parent of an unordered list for CSS?

I have something like the following:

```html
<div class="content">
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Item A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Item B</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I need to grab only Item 1 for altering it's CSS. I've attempted things like:
ul li a - won't work because it will grab Item 2

1. ul li a - won't work because it will grab Item 2
2. ul.navigation li - won't work because it will grab Item 2
3. ul:first-child - won't work because it will hit Item 1 and Sub Item A

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```css
.navigation > li:first-child > a {color: red}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Item A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Item B</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Or like this:

```css
.navigation > li:first-of-type > a {color: red}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Item A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Item B</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```